# Yii2 Query - join appears twice in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I tried to do a database-query including a join with yii2 advanced framework (v2.0.4)

```
  $query = new \yii\db\Query;
  $res = $query->select('date')->from(Heartbeat::tableName())
       ->join('INNER JOIN', Client::tableName(), 'id = client_id')
       ->where(['name' => $client])
       ->orderBy('date DESC')->limit(1)->scalar();
```

The SQL being executed was:

```
 SELECT `date` FROM `heartbeat`  
 INNER JOIN `client` ON id = client_id 
 INNER JOIN `client` ON id = client_id  
 WHERE `name`='CLIENT01' ORDER
 BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1
```

What is wrong with my code? **Why does the join appear twice?**

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `'name'` field in  `where(['name' => $client])` does not exists in `Heartbeat` table but it does in `Client`, and `INNER JOIN` is added due to table relations detected by Yii